# Puzzle image code I want more images for aromatic sliding page

Tags: php, mysql

Below is my Puzzle image code. I have getting only one image because of onload function so please suggest me to getting more image

this file is include in my main html code but one Image will be displayed and another is display NULL

```
<html>  
<head>  

    <title>HTML5 Puzzle Game</title>  

    <script type="text/javascript"> 

    window.onload = onReady;


var can;  
var ctx;          
var img;  
var clickX;  
var clickY;  
var selected1;  
var selected2;        
var blockSize   = 160;  
var piecesArray = new Array();  

function onReady()  
{  

    can = document.getElementById('myCanvas');  

    ctx        = can.getContext('2d');            
    img        = new Image();  
    img.onload = onImage1Load;  
    img.src    = "images/<?php echo $crows['product_image1']; ?>";  


}  

function onImage1Load()  
{  
    var r;  
    for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++)  
    {  
        for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++)  
        {  
            r = new Rectangle(i * blockSize, j * blockSize, i*blockSize + blockSize, j * blockSize + blockSize);  
            piecesArray.push(r);  
        }                 
    }  

    scrambleArray(piecesArray, 30);  
    drawImage();  
} 

function Rectangle(left, top, right, bottom)  
{  
    this.left = left;  
    this.top  = top;  
    this.right = right;  
    this.bottom = bottom;  

    this.width = right - left;  
    this.height = bottom - top;  
} 

function scrambleArray(ar, times)  
{  
    var count = 0;  
    var temp;  
    var index1;  
    var index2;  

    while(count < times)  
    {  
        index1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*piecesArray.length);  
        index2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*piecesArray.length);  

        temp = piecesArray[index1];  
        piecesArray[index1] = piecesArray[index2];  
        piecesArray[index2] = temp;  

        count++;  
    }  
}  

function drawImage()  
{  
    var r;  
    for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++)  
    {  
        for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++)  
        {  
            r = piecesArray[i*3+j];                   
            ctx.drawImage(img, r.left, r.top, r.width, r.height, i*blockSize, j*blockSize, blockSize, blockSize);  
            ctx.strokeStyle = "#fff"; 
        }  
    }  
} 

function highlightRect(drawX, drawY)  
{  
    ctx.beginPath();  
    ctx.moveTo(drawX, drawY);  
    ctx.lineTo(drawX + blockSize, drawY);  
    ctx.lineTo(drawX + blockSize, drawY + blockSize);  
    ctx.lineTo(drawX, drawY + blockSize);  
    ctx.lineTo(drawX, drawY);  
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;  

    // set line color  
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#fff";  
    ctx.stroke();  
}  

function swapRects(r1, r2)  
{  
    var index1;  
    var index2;  
    var temp = r1;  

    index1 = piecesArray.indexOf(r1);  
    index2 = piecesArray.indexOf(r2);  

    piecesArray[index1] = r2;  
    piecesArray[index2] = temp;           
}

function onCanvasClick(evt)  
{  
    clickX = evt.offsetX;  
    clickY = evt.offsetY;  

    var drawX         = Math.floor(clickX / blockSize);  
    var drawY         = Math.floor(clickY / blockSize);           
    var index         = drawX * 3 + drawY;            
    var targetRect    = piecesArray[index];  
    var drawHighlight = true;  

    drawX *= blockSize;  
    drawY *= blockSize;  

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 640, 480);  

    if(selected1 != undefined && selected2 != undefined)  
    {  
        selected1 = selected2 = undefined;  
    }  

    if(selected1 == undefined)  
    {  
        selected1 = targetRect;  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        selected2 = targetRect;  
        swapRects(selected1, selected2);  
        drawHighlight = false;  
    }  

    drawImage();  

    if(drawHighlight)     
        highlightRect(drawX, drawY);  
}  

    </script>  

</head>  

<body>  

    <div style="margin:0 auto; width:640px; height:480px; border: 4px none #cc6699;">  

       <canvas id="myCanvas" width="640" height="480" onclick="onCanvasClick(event);" style="border:1px dotted #fff;">  
       </canvas>  

    </div>  

</body>  

</html>
```

Comment: Your img.src variable only contain path to single image file, change it dynamically or loop through the images to load all.

Comment: suggest me for what another function have to put on window.onload(). Because this function call only one time i have to call this function when my page is getting slid

Comment: In onReady() function you need to insert new Image() for each image you need to fetch. It depends upon your php code.

Comment: Already this code is in while loop so this will be getting values but window.onload function call when page is loading then another all images cant displayed. so I have to call this Ready function to anther function ...??

Comment: Window.onload will only works once your page is loading for the first time, so yes you need to call your function where loop is used to display the images.

Comment: Just wondering: why is this tagged as PHP and MySQL?

Comment: Because of my code is in php and this file include there and also the image is getting from table that's y im putting sql and php